# angular and rails partial locals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, angularjs, partials

I'm trying to parameterize angular `JS` variables inside my rails partials, I have searched for the right syntax and couldn't able to get one. Not sure if I'm trying to do something that's not gonna work or just missing the correct syntax. Please provide me the right syntax or tell me the alternate way of approaching this.

```
= render "page/customPage", :items => "{{asset.set1}}"
= render "page/customPage", :items => "{{asset.set2}}"
```

In the Partial

```
%div{"ng-repeat" => "item in items"}
 %p do something
```

the above code didn't work

Comment: Why do you pass items in the render call?

Comment: we're going to need some context here. Why do you mix server-side and client-side rendering ? I know Angular just a bit, but i'd say rendering templates should only be managed client-side, using __directives__ for instance. Your rails app should only serve json content and let the angular app manage template rendering.